# Adding reactions to a message. Discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.6, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add a reaction to a message with a custom emoji, for some reason I can't find much online regarding this and I've spent the last 30m trying to figure out different approaches. Nothing's worked so far.

This is inside the cog.

1st approach

```py
accept_decline = await ctx.send("Test")
cross = self.bot.get_emoji(558322190060093441)
checkM = self.bot.get_emoji(558322116685070378)
await accept_decline.add_reaction(checkM)
await accept_decline.add_reaction(cross)
```

Another approach

```
accept_decline = await ctx.send("Test")
await self.bot.add_reaction(accept_decline, emoji="<:greenCheckmark:558322116685070378>")
await self.bot.add_reaction(accept_decline, emoji="<:redCross:423541694600970243>")
```

Nothing seems to happen nor do anything errors appear in the console.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is just to give the name/str/unicode symbole of your emoji :

> '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'

> '\U0001F44D'

> ''

and then create a variable containing it :

```
emoji = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
```

then you can send your message and add the reaction to it :

```
message = await ctx.send('test')
await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

At the end, you should get :

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send('test')
    emoji = '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}'
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Check the FAQ :
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-add-a-reaction-to-a-message

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<>` from the emotes.
`await self.bot.add_reaction(accept_decline, emoji="redCross:423541694600970243")` should work.

Answer (score 0):

The second approach is for Async.
Are you using a cog? If not turn `self.bot` to `bot`
Also are you sure the bot is in the server the emoji it's trying to get is in?
You could have a wrong ID, This below should work fine and you didn't tell us the error you're getting so it's hard to uncdertsnad what's the matter as well, if you're getting the error saying `self is not defined` then you're not using a cog and should change `self.bot` to `bot` because the script below works very well to me:

```py
accept_decline = await ctx.send("Test")
cross = self.bot.get_emoji(558322190060093441)
checkM = self.bot.get_emoji(558322116685070378)
await accept_decline.add_reaction(checkM)
await accept_decline.add_reaction(cross)
```